# EventStore expectedVersionException but event was stored

Tags: event-sourcing, optimistic-concurrency, eventstoredb

We use EventStore 5.0.0 and we faced with the following situation:

when we store event, sometimes, C# client receives response with error. Error from log:

```
EventStore.ClientAPI.Exceptions.WrongExpectedVersionException: Append failed due to WrongExpectedVersin. Stream: QWE.Api.SomeClassifier.Actors.ProductInfoActors.ProductActor-q5839583-5r82-5k30-sl13-1t485329g395, Expected version: 13, CurrentVersion:14
```

Disregard this response with error, event is stored with version 14.

What could it be the reason of this error message, while event was really stored?
We think the problem is in slow ssd, or high load.

Comment: Are you sure the event got stored though?

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like Event 14 is already in there.

Comment: @YoEight, yes, i'm sure event got stored

Answer (score 0):

This is the database built-in optimistic concurrency check. You can find more about it here: https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/appending-events/#handling-concurrency